# How do I combine several module.exports in Next.js next.config.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In my next.config.js file, I want to export two module exports. But I can't do that without combining them. Is there a way to combine the two module.exports?

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
  future: { webpack5: true },
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    swSrc: "service-worker.js",
  },
});

module.exports = {
  env: {
    SANITY_DATASET_NAME: process.env.SANITY_DATASET_NAME,
    SANITY_PROJECT_ID: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to export two modules, you suppose to export a single configuration object.

Check all possible NextJS configurations [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/packages/next/next-server/server/config-shared.ts).

```
const withPWA = require("next-pwa");

module.exports = withPWA({
  future: { webpack5: true },
  pwa: {
    dest: "public",
    swSrc: "service-worker.js",
  },
  env: {
    SANITY_DATASET_NAME: process.env.SANITY_DATASET_NAME,
    SANITY_PROJECT_ID: process.env.SANITY_PROJECT_ID,
  },
});
```